# Bot Discord Python : Problem with automatic sending of messages

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

My goal is to create a Discord bot to send a message to a room at specific times and days. Unfortunately I have a problem, my python bot declares two errors : `Task exception was never retrieved future: <Task finished name = 'Task-1' coro = <job () done"` and `"await client.send (message, channel) AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send' AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send'` and the bot does not send the desired message despite it starting up.

Here is my code:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

client = discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Hello !")

@bot.event
async def job():
    channel = client.get_channel(ID)
    message = ('Hello !')
    await client.send(message, channel)

    sched = BlockingScheduler()
    sched.add_job(job, 'cron', month='1-12', day_of_week='mon-sun', hour='0-23')
    sched.start()
    
client.loop.create_task(job())
   
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `client.send` you can use the channel directly using the `channel.send` method!

```py
async def job():
    channel = client.get_channel(ID)
    message = "Hello !"
    await channel.send(message)

    # rest of your code here.
```

**Refrences:**

[TextChannel#send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately the problem persists and displays the same first error but the second says: `"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'"`.

Comment: That probably means the channel does not exist.